# Update Google Latitude location from 3rd party android app

Tags: android, google-latitude

I am working on an app that uses the GPS on my g1.  I'm wondering if it is possible that when I am using the app I can have it update my Google Latitude location every x number of minutes.  Any thoughts on how this may be accomplished?

Comment: What do you mean with google latitud location?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Latitude REST API, http://code.google.com/apis/latitude/overview.html